# Shortcut for print() function in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

Yes I know that using print() as a function rather than a statement is "better" in a bunch of ways. I still hate it, in part because it makes debugging and checking things so much more annoying. If you had a line

```
do_thing(stuff)
```

and you wanted to see if it was doing what you thought it was, you could just add a print to it and get

```
print do_thing(stuff)
```

However, adding the parentheses can sometimes be a bit fiddly.

Yes I know I'm lazy, but is there a shortcut in Spyder or other consoles for highlighting a line of text and putting a print() wrapper around it like it does for parentheses (which is about 80:20 useful:annoying)

Thanks!

Comment: Laziness is not a valid reason to ask a question of this nature on this site.

Comment: I apologize for the flippancy. This ties into a deeper question about more complicated function-type shortcuts in Spyder, but did not actually point that out.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can do this, and not only for `print` but for any function, by going to the menu

```
Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Advanced settings > Autocall
```

and selecting there the `Smart` or `Full` options.

To learn about the difference between them, please go [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-autocall) (`Smart` is equivalent to `Active` and `Full` to `Active always`).

Comment: That's really cool!  From the documentation, that looks like it's available more broadly in python in general?

Comment: Yeah, as I said, once you enable that option, you can write `foo 1` instead of `foo(1)` for any Python function called `foo`.